# count the same character which comes in sequence

Tags: python

```
def count_squences(string):

    i= 0 
    total = 0
    total_char_list = []

    while i < len(string):
        print(string[i])

        if string[i] == "x":
            total += 1
        if string[i] == "y":

            total_char_list.append(total)
            total = 0

        i = i + 1

    return total_char_list


print(count_squences("xxxxyyxyxx"))
```

I am trying to return the most used x characters in a file format. for example this functions should return [4, 1, 2].

For example if string is "xxxxxyxxyxxx' it should return [5, 2, 3]

My function does not return the correct list. Any helps would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: `def count_x(s):return [len(t) for t in re.findall('x+', s)]` will also accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not resetting your counter when you encounter a `y` character, and you should only append to `total_char_list` if there was at least one `x` character counted by the time you find a `y` character (`y` characters could be duplicated too):

```
total = 0
while i < len(string):
    if string[i] == "x":
        total += 1
    if string[i] == "y":
        if total:
            total_char_list.append(total)
        total = 0

    i = i + 1
```

Next, when the loop *ends* and `total` is not zero, you need to append that value too, or you won't be counting `'x'` characters at the end of the sequence:

```
while ...:
    # ...

if total:
    # x characters at the end
    total_char_list.append(total)
```

Next, you really want to use a `for` loop to loop over a sequence. You are given the individual characters that way:

```
total = 0
for char in string:
    if char == 'x':
        total += 1
    if char == 'y':
        if total:
            total_charlist.append(total)
        total = 0

if total:
    # x characters at the end
    total_char_list.append(total)
```

You can make this faster with [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

def count_squences(string):
    return [sum(1 for _ in group) for char, group in groupby(string) if char == 'x']
```

`groupby()` divides up an iterable input (such as a string) into separate iterators per group, where a group is defined as any consecutive value with the same `key(value)` result. The default `key()` function just returns the value, so `groupby(string)` gives you groups of consecutive characters that are the same. `char` is the repeated character, and `sum(1 for _ in group)` takes the length of an iterator.

You can then make it more generic, and count all groups:

```
def count_all_sequences(string):
    counts = {}
    for char, group in groupby(string):
        counts.setdefault(char, []).append(sum(1 for _ in group))
    return counts
```

The same can be done with a regular expression:

```
import re

def count_all_sequences(string):
    counts = {}
    # (.)(\1*) finds repeated characters; (.) matching one, \1 matching the same
    # This gives us (first, rest) tuples, so len(rest) + 1 is the total length
    for char, group in re.findall(r'(.)(\1*)', string):
        counts.setdefault(char, []).append(len(group) + 1)
    return counts
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't initialize the value of `total` between the sequences so it keeps on counting.

```
def count_squences(string):
    i= 0 
    total = 0
    total_char_list = []
    while i < len(string):
        if string[i] == "x":
            total += 1
        if string[i] == "y":
            if total != 0:
                total_char_list.append(total)
                total = 0
        i = i + 1
    if total != 0:
       total_char_list.append(total)
    return total_char_list
```

Update (17:00) - fixed the original procedure and I thought of a better solution -

```
my_str = "xxxxyyxyxx"
[len(z) for z in re.split("y+", my_str)]
```

Comment: This will append multiple zeros when there are consecutive `y` characters.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters, I fixed it + another fix

Answer (score -1):

Edited for function format:

```
def count_sequences(string):
    return [len(x) for x in re.findall(r"x+", string)]

count_sequences("xxxxyyxyxx")
```

returns [4,1,2]